# Symfony el formulario no guarda

Tags: php, formularios, symfony, doctrine

Les comento que estoy desarrollando un formulario en symfony 3.4, el formulario se renderiza correctamente y se muestra por pantalla. El problema sucede que al hacer click en el input submit no sucede nada cuando deberia guardarme en la base de datos.
El codigo para  guardar lo ingresado en el formulario es:

```
   public function agregar(Request $request)
{
    $persona = new Persona();
    $formulario = $this->createForm(PersonaType::class,$persona);
 //   $this->render('base.html.twig',array("persona"=>$formulario->createView()));
    $formulario->handleRequest($request);
    if($formulario -> isSubmitted() && $formulario->isValid())
    {
        $persona = $formulario->getData();

        $db = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $db->persist($persona);
        $db->flush();

        return new Response('<html>hola </html>');
    }
    else
    {
        return new Response('<html>chau </html>');
    }
}
```

Lo muestro de la siguiente manera:

```
     /**
 * @Route("/post", name="post_list")
 */
public function mostar()
{
    $formulario = $this->createForm(PersonaType::class);
    return $this->render('base.html.twig',array("persona"=>$formulario->createView()));
}
```

En twig

```
    <h2>Formulario con Symfony3</h2>
{{form(persona)}}
{{form_end(persona)}}
```

Intente asociar una ruta al metodo agregar() pero no funciono y sinceramente estoy perdido de como hacer funcionar,
Espero sus respuestas.
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a emplear el helper del formulario **form()** no tienes que usar el form_end, y si vas a usar form_end debes comenzar con form_start. Debes indicar un nombre a tu acción de agregar, en este ejemplo asumo que sea agregar_persona, solo para darte una muestra de como hacerlo, en fin tu twig debe quedar de esta manera:

```
{{ form(persona, {'action': path('agregar_persona')}) }}
```

O

```
{{ form_start(persona, {'action': path('agregar_persona')}) }}
{{ form_end(persona) }}
```

Aunque form_end te renderice todos tus campos del formulario es recomendable usar form_widget según la página oficial de Symfony http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-the-form, es decir:

```
{{ form_start(persona, {'action': path('agregar_persona')}) }}
{{ form_widget(persona) }}
{{ form_end(persona) }}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Con tu comentario me di cuenta de que debía asociar una ruta a mi metodo agregar()

Comment: Si te ayudó mi respuesta por favor acéptala como respuesta.

Comment: Hola! El sistema no me deja porque soy inicial y no tengo reputación. Igualmente muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Aunque seas principiante el sistema si te deja solo marca la pestaña debajo de la puntuación de mi respuesta al lado izquierdo de la misma.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente, puntuado.

Comment: OKOK gracias  a ti